# Select first row where the status is false

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a html table and i want to select the first row which meets the condition `status is false`

```
<table>
   <th>
     ....
     ....
   </th>
   <tr>
       <input class="status" id="txtStatus_0" name="StudentReceipt[0].Status" type="hidden" value="True">
       <td>             
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
       ....
       ....
   </tr> 
    <tr>
       <input class="status" id="txtStatus_1" name="StudentReceipt[1].Status" type="hidden" value="False">
       <td>             
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
       ....
       ....
   </tr>      
    <tr>
       <input class="status" id="txtStatus_2" name="StudentReceipt[2].Status" type="hidden" value="False">
       <td>             
       </td>
       <td>
       </td>
       ....
       ....
   </tr> 

</table>
```

Of course I can use the foreach loop and can Iterate over the entire row and gets the first row with status is false.But Is there any other way of finding it out by using `Jquery selectors`

Comment: "*Of course I can use the foreach loop and can Iterate over the entire row and gets the first row with status is false*" - great; and how would you do this? Incidentally your HTML is invalid; get rid of the ellipses (they add nothing pertinent to your code and make it more awkward to copy and paste to form a working example), and the ***only*** valid children of a `<tr>` element is `<td>` or `<th>`, *nothing* else. At all. Certainly not an `<input>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[value=False]:first').closest('tr');
```

`:first` is **CSS selector** which `jquery` uses and `value=First` will be the **attribute selector**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nc4mra0w/1/)**

Comment: `:first` is *not* a CSS selector, or pseudo-class; that's purely jQuery/Sizzle. The CSS selector that you might have confused it with is [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) or, possibly, [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for clarifying.. Yea, I confused with terms..?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want

```
$('[value=False]').first().parent()
```

Finds all inputs with the value `False`, gets the first one, then gets the parent (the row)

Comment: what does value mean??

Comment: It's the HTML attribute, like CSS. For example, if you wanted the first with the type of hidden you could do `$('[type=hidden]').first().parent()`

Comment: Input should be the child element of td. OP's html is not valid